# Issue with wrap_content in ExoPlayerView. ExoPlayerView height remain 0 at run-time if it set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-wrap-content

I want my player to adapt the height of video so I'm using Exo player view with wrap_content height.
but it's not working.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView                     
                        android:id="@+id/exoplayerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:resize_mode="fill"
                        app:use_controller="false">

                    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
```